# A linear transformation can be decomposed as a sum of two invertible tranformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove that if $\text{Char}(K) \neq 2$ and $V$ is finite dimensional, then $T \in \text{Hom}_{K}(V,V)$ can be expressed as the sum of two invertible linear transformations.

Proof: Choose $\lambda  \neq 0 \in K$ such that $S = T - \lambda I$ is invertible. Then $T = S + \lambda I$ with both $S$ and $\lambda I$ invertible linear transformations.

P.S: I have seen the same claim made for matrices previously and the solution I saw broke into cases such as assuming first the matrix A is invertible and then considering the sum involving division by two and then the other case used writing A in a block form that would make it easier. But my one line proof above seems to work nicely though or am I making an obvious mistake?

Comment: You may not actually find such a lambda in K if char K=2 . For example the characteristic equation maybe the equation of the finite field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by a comment, your proof is wrong because $\lambda$ may not exist. For instance, suppose $V=GF(2)=\{0,1\}$ and $T=I$ is the identity map. Now $T$ is the only invertible linear map on $V$, but $T+T=0\ne T$.

To prove the proposition, you may consider first the special case where $V$ is two-dimensional, $\{x_1,x_2\},\{y_1,y_2\}$ are two ordered bases of $V$ and $T$ is a non-invertible linear transformation such that
$$
\begin{cases}
T(x_1)=0,\\
T(x_2)=y_2.
\end{cases}
$$
Try to write $T$ as a sum of two invertible linear transformations in this case. Then try to generalise this construction for a general $V$ and a general $T$ with a general (and possibly zero) nullspace.